# TimePicker: change text size of selected time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have a `TimePicker`. I want to change the `textSize` of only the selected time. I searched and I did not get any answers which solves my issue. Below is the code.

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/start_time_picker"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Theme given for activity :

```
<style name="timePickerAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/Theme.MyTheme.TimePicker</item>
</style>
```

Is there any library for this?

Comment: have you tried MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: @Madhuri . Hi. I didn't get your clear requirement. but for textsize dynamically for any type device you can use https://github.com/intuit/sdp
library

Comment: You can not have this behavior with the native picker. You need to customize it .

Comment: @ADM so will I have to use Number picker and customize it ? Isn't there any library ?

Comment: @nihal_softy When the user selects the time, the text size should increase.

Comment: There maybe a library for it . Cause its kind of same feature as IOS Time picker . Most of the similar libraries for android  are seems abandoned.  Keep searching ..

Comment: @madhuriHR Means when you select Time fro TimePIcker textView should be increased format ? And it must be device based ? Am i right ?

Comment: @madhuriHR You can go through this Library https://github.com/nomanr/ZoomTextView

Comment: @nihal_softy I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: @madhuriHR just allow me 5 minutes. I am doing on it. after that I will share code with you

Comment: @madhuriHR Please use this library and modify it accordingly https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider